# Full Linux Install On USB Drive - GRUB Problems

Tags: linux, boot, usb, system-installation, grub

I recently bought a new laptop and decided to install Kali Linux on it. However, the laptop (an Asus Zenbook btw.) has a 128GB drive which is not very much. That is why I bought a 64GB, SanDisk, flat-profile usb, for extra storage.
Now here's what I did:

- First I took another usb and installed the Kali System Installer on it with Rufus.
- Next I plucked them both in the laptop and began the install.
- I partitioned the SanDisk usb into 3 partitions, one 15GB (for the system), another 45GB (for other storage use) and a 2GB swap.
- The install finished successfully and the next time I started the laptop it went into GRUB and then booted into a fully functionally Kali Linux operating system.

However, when I remove the usb and boot the system, it complains that it can't find GRUB (obviously), because the device does not exist (because I removed it).

```
Welcome to Grub!

error: no such device: f8fe7846-b10c-ae13-1e8964d21edd
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>_
```

So my question is if there is any way to tell grub to automatically start windows if it fails to launch. Is that a possibility?

I'm sorry if I'm not clear, it's kinda hard to explain. So, basically, what I want my laptop to do is to start grub ONLY if the usb is plugged and to directly boot into Windows if it's not detected.

Is there a default boot script or anything to detect devices before it even boots? Could I edit that in some way?

A am an intermediate Linux user so all this isn't really new to me, but I really couldn't find anything on the web.

Comment: The problem isn't that grub isn't starting; the problem is that grub is starting, but it can't find the partition that contains the boot files.

Comment: Hm. So is there a way to prevent grub from starting in the first place and let the machine know that there is no boot media and skip directly to windows?

Comment: You could instead have grub start up and then tell it to boot into Windows. That would be far easier (assuming Windows exists on both/all systems).

Comment: Ok, but the problem is that it doesn't boot into grub, it just goes into rescue mode. Would I be able to make my bios detect if the device is even connected in the first place. Because the Bios tries to boot from the usb which does not even exist. Also, I don't really want to install grub on my windows (main) partition because of the inconvenience of boot time and visuals. I know that there are keys like f7 that display boot devices. Maybe I could set default boot to windows and configure a hotkey that automatically changes the boot device? Do you have any idea how to do that?